# Asking the user to input a char and then a string

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple program that asks a user to input a letter. And then I want him to input a phrase. When it's just a single string I don't have a problem.

```
char c;
string s;
cin >> c;
cin >> s;
```

But when I want a phrase

```
cin >> c;
getline(cin, s);
```

When I run the program after the user inputs a letter and hits enter I don't get a chance to input the phrase. Of course if I type the character and enter a phrase after a space the program works fine.

On the contrary when I input a character and then enter a single string after a space using the first method, it won't record the string.

Why does it do this?

Comment: Use `cin.ignore()`... or just stop mixing `>>` and `getline`. Use one of the two, but not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When ever you write a character and press enter, actually 2 char are send to the buffer: the character itself and `\n` as the result of the enter key press. Your `cin >> c;` reads the first character only while `\n` still remains in the buffer. Since `std::getline()` reads everything before it encounters a `\n` character and since `\n` is the first character it encounters it doesn't read anything and the program terminates. Add a `std::cin.ignore();` (to ignore the `\n`) before `std::getline` and the code will work.

Comment: How does this concept differ for the case of a string input using just cin instead of getline()? When I just use cin >> s; after cin >> c; it seems to work just fine.

Comment: `std::cin()` finds the first non-newline and non-whitespace character and reads till it encounters one. So `\n` is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Since c only takes a character, the enter key that the user presses is given to s so anything other than that is not recorded. Only press a single key and no enter for the character. Or else just use a string anyway.